# How can I add webmaster tools to my Sinatra web application?

Tags: html, ruby, heroku, sinatra, google-search-console

I am trying to put the Google Webmaster Tools html verification file into my Sinatra web application.

So far, I have tried a few methods, including simply adding the file to the root directory, and then adding the file to my views directory, and finally by keeping my file in my views directory, but including the following in my server.rb file:

```
get 'googlee35f528f82dc08c.html' do

  erb :googlee35f528f82dc08c
end
```

Currently, when I visit the site at `mysite.com/googlee35f528f82dc08c.html` it simply says `Not Found`. How can I add Google's Webmaster Tool's verification HTML file to my Sinatra web application in such a way that it will be found when I visit `mysite.com/googlee35f528f82dc08c.html` ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried just putting a googleXXXX.html file in your app's `:public_folder` directory?

Comment: @nickveys Yeah, usually you can just leave this as a static file and let your `httpd` server take care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks so much, I ended up just putting a tag in the head of the index file, as in `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="93dIUokTQmvpbTzuSVxnq1wWWriIJyk2wa6w" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting a tag in the head of the index file, as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="93dIUokTQmvpbTzuSVxnq1wWWriIJyk2wa6w" />
</head>
```